# OLEDB: What is the fastest way to get column metadata for a SQL Server CE table, without selecting any rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, oledb

I have to use OLE DB with an SQL Server CE. My task is to obtain the metadata on all the columns in a table.

One way to do it is select all the fields of any row and then obtain `IColumnInfo` from the resulting row set. However, this is done at the cost of selecting a row.

My question - is it the fastest way or is there a better way to get hold on the `DBCOLUMNINFO` objects for all the columns in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid selecting rows, use `where 1 = 0` as your where clause.

You could also use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

Microsoft docs: [Information Schema (SQL Server Compact)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156.aspx)

Comment: The question is whether I get `DBCOLUMNINFO` objects, which have all the column metadata conveniently packaged in one structure per column or do I have to access the rowset, fetch the columns and parse them. For instance, if a column is of type I4, then the field `DBCOLUMNINFO.wType` equals 3 - no parsing is needed.

Comment: I am not that experienced with databases. Does specifying `where 1 = 0` cause the database to check every row for this condition or is the database smart enough to understand that no row is going to satisfy it?

Comment: It will know to return an empty record set.

Comment: Yes, but how does it arrive at the empty record set? Does it know upfront that the record set is empty or does it learn it the hard way - by testing the condition against each and every row?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a SELECT statement on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to extract COLUMN information for a particular table:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?
```

However, in OLEDB there's an IDBSchemaRowset which can be a lot faster. I've put together a small C++ code sample that shows opening an OLEDB connection (OpenDatabase) and extracting column information using IRowset (GetSchemaColumns). You need to add processing the results from IRowset returned (Run):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <oleauto.h>
#include <oledb.h>

HRESULT OpenDatabase(LPOLESTR szPath, IDBInitialize **ppIDBInitialize)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IDBInitialize> spIDBInitialize;
    hr = spIDBInitialize.CoCreateInstance(OLESTR("Microsoft.SQLLITE.MOBILE.OLEDB.3.0"));
    CComPtr<IDBProperties> spIDBProperties;
    spIDBProperties = spIDBInitialize;
    CComVariant vDataSource(szPath);
    DBPROP dbProp = { DBPROP_INIT_DATASOURCE, DBPROPOPTIONS_REQUIRED, 0, DB_NULLID, vDataSource };
    DBPROPSET dbPropSet = { &dbProp, 1, DBPROPSET_DBINIT };
    hr = spIDBProperties->SetProperties(1, &dbPropSet);
    hr = spIDBInitialize->Initialize();
    *ppIDBInitialize = spIDBInitialize.Detach();
    return hr;
}

HRESULT GetSchemaColumns(IUnknown *pDataSource, LPOLESTR pTableName, IRowset **ppIRowset)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IDBCreateSession> spIDBCreateSession;
    hr = pDataSource->QueryInterface(IID_IDBCreateSession, (void**) &spIDBCreateSession);
    CComPtr<IDBCreateCommand> spIDBCreateCommand;
    hr = spIDBCreateSession->CreateSession(NULL, IID_IDBCreateCommand, (IUnknown**) &spIDBCreateCommand);
    CComPtr<IDBSchemaRowset> spIDBSchemaRowset;
    hr = spIDBCreateCommand->QueryInterface(IID_IDBSchemaRowset, (void**) &spIDBSchemaRowset);
    CComVariant vRestrictions[CRESTRICTIONS_DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS];
    vRestrictions[2] = pTableName;
    CComPtr<IRowset> spIRowset;
    hr = spIDBSchemaRowset->GetRowset(NULL, DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS, CRESTRICTIONS_DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS, vRestrictions, IID_IRowset, NULL, NULL, (IUnknown**) &spIRowset);
    *ppIRowset = spIRowset.Detach();
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Run()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<IDBInitialize> spIDBInitialize;
    hr = OpenDatabase(OLESTR("MyDatabase.sdf"), &spIDBInitialize);
    CComPtr<IRowset> spIRowset;
    hr = GetSchemaColumns(spIDBInitialize, OLESTR("MyTableName"), &spIRowset);
    DBCOUNTITEM cRows = 0;
    HROW hRow = NULL;
    HROW *phRow = &hRow;
    hr = spIRowset->GetNextRows(DB_NULL_HCHAPTER, 0, 1, &cRows, &phRow);
    while (SUCCEEDED(hr) && cRows > 0)
    {
        // Do handling of a row fetched from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN here
        // ...
        hr = spIRowset->ReleaseRows(1, phRow, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        hr = spIRowset->GetNextRows(DB_NULL_HCHAPTER, 0, 1, &cRows, &phRow);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Is it faster than doing a select with `where 1=0` and then acquiring the `IColumnInfo` reference from the returned `IRowset` object? Because this way I get `DBCOLUMNINFO` objects, which are obviously more convenient than extracting the same data from a rowset (and parsing the type names - something one does not have to do if having `DBCOLUMNINFO` objects at one's disposal).

Comment: In terms of "faster" this decision is ultimately up to you because some applications both techniques may have negligible difference. From a purest perspective, a SQL SELECT must be processed through the SQL parser before the IColumnInfo is available, whereas the IDBSchemaRowset is direct access to the internals of the database, so, it should be faster. Generally, I have had very good performance experience with IDBSchemaRowset so, definitely, it's worthwhile to master.